# Are there any "sure" ways to tell what is a boundary for the purpose of Stokes' Theorem?

Tags: stokes-theorem

If I had a region bounded by the surface $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ and a plane $x+y+z=1$, how would I determine what "boundary" I'd take the line integral over? Or would I take it over both boundaries?
The first being the circle of radius 3 with centre at the origin on the x-y plane
and the second, being the "ellipse-looking" boundary at the top (so the equation that comes out when we solve those two simultaneously)
?
Image of the region (so that small wedge above the x-y plane and below the surface plane): https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNdF9.png?
Website used: https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Comment: Thanks. Why can't it also be the circle at the x-y plane?  
Iirc, I did a question that had to do with a hemisphere, laying on the x-y plane. We treated the boundary of this hemisphere surface to be that circle on the x-y plane. If we were to intersect this with a similar plane in the OP, would the new boundary be that intersection?

Comment: The ellipse just isn't a subset of the $xy$-plane: As you can check, $(3, 0, -2)$ is on the circle. I'm not sure I understand the second question---perhaps you can specify exactly the surfaces?

Comment: My bad. I'll give explicit examples:  
So I did a question before that treated the  surface $S$ where $S$ is the hemisphere: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $z \geq 0$, and claimed that the boundary (for our line integral via Stoke's) is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ at $z=0$ (so the $x-y$ plane) and intuitively, this makes sense.  
  
However, what if we had say another surface that bounds the hemisphere and  that intersected this hemisphere e.g. so the surface $x+y+z=1$?  
What will we say the boundary (to use for Stoke's) would be of this new surface (the one that is bounded by the hemisphere,..

Comment: but is below that other surface)? Is it that intersection it makes with the hemisphere?  
Pic: http://i.imgur.com/m4Tof8P.png?1

Comment: After you "explicit examples" I'm now not sure I even understood your original question the way you meant it to be interpreted. I don't know what you mean by "another surface that bounds the hemisphere".

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by "this new surface (the one that is bounded by the hemisphere)". In general, surfaces are bounded by curves, not other surfaces.

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity. My question basically boils down to: Given a region which is composed of multiple surfaces, how do we know what boundary to choose for Stoke's Theorem?  
The example with the hemisphere (without the extra plane cutting through it) has an obvious(?) boundary curve of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ on the $x-y$ plane. However, one we introduce another surface (in this case, the plane $x+y+z=1$), it slices through the hemisphere. Now considering the solid bounded by this new plane and the original hemisphere, if I pull it (just that region enclosed) out, it looks like....

Comment: there's another ""flat"" face (which is the new intersection). My intuition first told me that the flat face of the original hemisphere (on the $x-y$ plane) was the boundary, but now that there is an additional "flat" face, the curve that bounds this "flat" face seems to be another boundary as well.

Comment: Right, so in this configuration there's more than one distinguished, bounded surface, and those surfaces have different boundaries.

Comment: Hmm, so if I were to take the line integral of the boundary C with a vector field $F$ that is the intersection mentioned previously, what would be the surface we are considering if we changed it to a surface integral by Stoke's? WIll this be different to if I took the line integral of D, the original boundary (the one on the x-y plane)?

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you're asking. I suggest you reframe your original question to include this subquestion, including specifying precisely which objects you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'm not sure how else to shape my question, but basically when you say "there's more than one distinguished, bounded surface", it seems to suggest (to me) that there's two surfaces $S_1,S_2$ and a vector field $F$ such that $\iint_{S_1}curlF d{\textbf{S}_1}$ and $\iint_{S_2}curlF d{\textbf{S}_2}$ are not necessarily equal, so by Stoke's Theorem (the reverse), there are two distinct line integrals, corresponding to those two (?) distinct boundaries I mentioned before (the one with the "flat" face and the original one on the x-y plane).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a couple issues here. First, there is no region bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the slanted plane $x+y+z=1$. The two surfaces split $\Bbb{R}^3$ into 4 unbounded regions:

- inside the cylinder and above the plane
- inside the cylinder and below the plane
- outside the cylinder and above the plane
- outside the cylinder and below the plane

Including the $xy$-plane $z=0$ creates a total of 10 regions, two of which are bounded. Adding the last condition that $z\geq 0$ finally clears up the region in question. Before we can even discuss what the boundary is, we need to have the region well-defined, so I will assume that the set we are referring to is

$$ \Omega = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2\leq 1)\wedge(x+y+z\leq 1)\wedge(z\geq 0) \} $$

From here, the components that make up the boundary are clear, and it brings up another issue. We are discussing a three-dimensional space, so we should have a two-dimensional boundary, which is consistent with what he have here. However, it is not consistent with use of the (Kelvin-)Stokes' Theorem, which is used on oriented two-dimensional surfaces with one-dimensional boundary. Without seeing the integral you intend to solve with this method, there's no way to answer the question, but this region that you seem to be defining isn't "compatible" with that form of Stokes' theorem (in the sense that the $\int_\Omega \text{curl}F\cdot \text dS = 0$ for any closed surface $\Omega$).

---

*Below, I will show how to find the boundary of the set $\Omega$ independent of its use in integration.*

So, the circle and ellipse curves will not be the entire boundary, since they are 1-dimensional curves. Nonetheless, they are *part* of the boundary. Just like the boundary of a solid cube is made up of faces (two-dimensional solid squares), edges (one-dimensional curves), and vertices (zero-dimensional points), we have the same situation for our solid here.

The faces are the truncated circular disk base, the truncated elliptical disk ceiling, and the cylindrical wall. We can get these two-dimensional boundary pieces by changing one inequalities in the definition of $\Omega$ to an equality, and changing the rest to strict inequalities. So, we get the base by restricting our points to those in the $xy$-plane:

$$\partial\Omega_{\text{base}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2< 1)\wedge(x+y+z< 1)\wedge(z= 0) \}$$

Note that we let $z=0$, so we could have written $x+y\leq 1$ explicitly for the second inequality. Similarly, we get the ceiling by restricting our points to those in the slanted plane:

$$\partial\Omega_{\text{ceiling}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2< 1)\wedge(x+y+z = 1)\wedge(z> 0) \}$$

and we get the wall by restricting our points to those on the cylinder:

$$\partial\Omega_{\text{wall}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2= 1)\wedge(x+y+z < 1)\wedge(z> 0) \}$$

Next, we can do a similar process to get the different 1-dimensional edge pieces by setting two inequalities to equalities at a time. This will give us three different edge pieces: the circular edge, the elliptical edge, and the linear edge. Explicitly,

$$\partial\Omega_{\text{circular}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2= 1)\wedge(x+y+z < 1)\wedge(z= 0) \} \\
\partial\Omega_{\text{elliptical}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2= 1)\wedge(x+y+z = 1)\wedge(z> 0) \} \\
\partial\Omega_{\text{linear}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2< 1)\wedge(x+y+z = 1)\wedge(z= 0) \}$$

Lastly, set all three inequalities to equality and you will get the two vertex points

$$\partial\Omega_{\text{vertices}} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x^2+y^2= 1)\wedge(x+y+z =1)\wedge(z=0) \}$$

We can construct the full boundary by taking the union of these pieces:

$$\partial\Omega = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha} \partial\Omega_\alpha $$

Note that this is a disjoint union; due to the use of strict inequalities mixed with equalities, it should be clear that no element of one piece could possibly be an element of another. This technique works in general for sets defined by inequalities like this, but you may find some pieces to be empty sets (such as the intersection of parallel faces of a cube).

Answer (score 0):

You would take the line integral over each boundary separately then add the two results together. Be sure to orient the curves in the correct way so that the both correspond to the outward normal. In this instance the curve on the xy plane would be counterclockwise as viewed from above and the "ellipse-looking" boundary would be oriented clockwise. This is how we learned to approach it in my multivariable class but have only used it with cylinders.